# Chess openings together with games played using this opening

Tags: opening, database

I am looking for a resource where I can get a list of chess openings (the more comprehensive the better) together with games that were played using this opening. Up till now the only good thing I was able to find is [chesstool](http://www.chesstoolpgn.com/Aeng.html). It is really good in terms of the number of openings and also it has quite a lot of games for each opening. The only bad thing is that apparently it does not have games after 2010 year.

Alternatively is there a place where I can get all (ok, I know that all sounds ridiculous) but at least all fide rated chess games in PGN format?

Comment: Online? http://www.chess.com/explorer/

Answer (score 2):

Try TWIC, each week they release at least the top-rated FIDE games.

http://www.theweekinchess.com/twic

Comment: Thank you, but it is a big hustle to collect all the games in this manner :-(

Comment: Try this, http://portablegamenotation.com/twictoolbox.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this (http://www.pgnmentor.com/files.html) might help (PGNs of various openings) though not sure how current the games are.

Comment: Cool, thanks the list of openings is big and the games are pretty updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Chessbase Online tool:

http://database.chessbase.com/js/apps/onlinedb/

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good site: http://www.365chess.com/

Free Javascript tool at http://www.chesslive.de/js/apps/onlinedb/

You can get Chessbase online App for your Android at
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=chessbase.android.chessdb&hl=en
or iphone at 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chessbase-online/id417726752

Comment: 365 chess is really good, but you can not easily see the list of openings with their moves. You have to click through your moves to figure out the opening. Also you can not get their database. I also was not able to find easily downloadable games from the second site.